# Polymorphism in PHP

Tags: php

I just learned PHP few weeks ago and now I want to know a little bit about the polymorphism in PHP. I get stuck with something like this:

```
    class A{
    var $n = 0;
    public function f1(){
        $this->n += 4;
        $m = f2();
        return $this->n + $this->m;
    }
    public function f2(){
        $this->n += 1;
        return $this->n;
    }
    public function f3(){
        f1();
        return $this->n;
    }

    class B extends A{
        public function f1(){
            $this->n -= 4;
            $m = f2();
            return $this->n - $this->m;
        }
        public function f2(){
            $this->n += $this->n;
            return $this->n;
        }
    }

    $b = new B();
    $b->n = 4;
    echo $b->f1()." ";
    echo $b->f2()." ";
    echo $b->f3()." ";
```

It has an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function f2()

However, the function f2() is mentioned on line `$m = f2();`.

What's wrong in this case?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: try to call f2 function with `$m = $this->f2();`

Comment: Sidenote: Look at these statements,`return $this->n + $this->m;` and `return $this->n - $this->m;`, neither class `A` nor class `B` has an instance variable `m`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you dont have a global function `f2` the way you should use it is 
this way `$this->f2();`

if you want to also call the parent method of your class B try `parent::f2();` which will call the method `f2()` of class A.

I hope it helps.